# Use password input with MaskedInput.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-validate, maskedinput

So I have searched around and thus far have not found the answer for this. The maskedInput.js plugin from DigitalBush is used a lot of places like a lot of masked input plugins. But all of them seem to only focus on masking the input format and not allowing the formatted mask to use a secure password field. Obviously, this is not a true security fix but a standard business requirement. So what I am trying to accomplish is just to use the HTML5 password input with the maskedInput.js plugin. This works except for the dashes are also represented as bullets as well so the mask becomes somewhat useless. If anyone has a solution that is not a hack please let me know. I have setup a Fiddle for testing that also has jqueryValidate on the input as these two plugins are typically found like peas and carrots throughout the web.

[The Sample Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jy70duf1/1/)

Sample:

```
 <input type="password" class="form-text" name="ssn" id="ssn" required="true" minlength="9" maxlength="9" aria-describedby="ssn-errors" placeholder="Social Security Number" >
```

Javascript with additional logic to force validation on blur:

```
    $("#ssn", "body")
            .mask("999-99-9999", {
                placeholder: "",
                autoclear: false
            })
            .bind("blur", function () {
                // force revalidate on blur to help with jquery.validate
                var frm = $(this).parents("form");
                // if form has a validator
                if ($.data(frm[0], 'validator')) {
                    var validator = $(this).parents("form").validate();
                    validator.settings.onfocusout.apply(validator, [this]);
                }
            });
```

My first theory is to change the input type from password to text on focus and change back on blur but it seems like this should be a standard option to use a password type with a mask in the days of SSNs, CC's and other NPD required on forms.

Your thoughts are welcome.

Comment: And from what I am seeing, it looks like changing the input type on focus and blur is a no-no so that option seems to be out.

Comment: The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the Validate plugin on your form.  You only call it once within DOM ready handler.  It never goes inside of another event handler... ever.

Comment: You also would not need to bind the `blur` event to it, when the `onfocusout` functionality is built into it and activated by default.